# How to fix state change in VUEX?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, store

I have a problem with changing state while splicing element from another array then changes in state. TO be clear, i don't want state to change, just want to splice one element from array  `arrayWithFilters = []`

```js
export const SHOW_RESULTS_WHEN_NOTHING = (state) => {
  let selectedFilters = {...state.selected.filters},
  arrayWithFilters = []; //Making splice from this array, but it also removes from state.selected.filters. 

  for (let filter in selectedFilters) {
    arrayWithFilters.push(selectedFilters[filter])
  }

  arrayWithFilters.forEach((filter) => {
    if (filter.values.includes('qcontrast')) {
      filter.values.splice('qcolor', 1);
      console.log(filter)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Where is `arrayWithFilters` declared? Ie, where is the `let arrayWithFilters` or `var arrayWithFilters`?

Comment: Your issue though is that you're only making a shallow copy of `state.selected.filters`. The `values` inside each `filter` will still refer to the same (array) object references

Answer (score 1):

problem solved with the next code

```
export const SHOW_RESULTS_WHEN_NOTHING = (state) => {
let selectedFilters = {...state.selected.filters},
    arrayWithFilters = [];

let selectedFiltersCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selectedFilters));

arrayWithFilters = Object.values(selectedFiltersCopy);

arrayWithFilters.forEach((filter) => {

    if (filter.values.includes('qcontrast')) {

        filter.values.splice('qcontrast', 1);

    }
})

console.log(arrayWithFilters)
```

}